# Secure Nifi with SSL

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, apache-nifi

I secure successfully a Nifi Node (localhost) with SSL but I have always a yellow padlock in my browser as you can see in the pic [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxXyM.png)
Do you have any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used an untrusted certificate then this is expected behavior. You would have to purchase a real certificate for a real domain name in order for the browser to not warn you.

Comment: Thanks Bryan
I've another question please (you can see it here: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/226357/difference-between-tls-toolkit-modes-standalone-an.html)

Answer (score 0):

I see the description below:
*Standalone : generates the certificate authority, keystores, truststores, and nifi.properties files in one command



Client/Server mode : uses a Certificate Authority Server that accepts Certificate Signing Requests from clients, signs them, and sends the resulting certificates back. Both client and server validate the other’s identity through a shared secret.*
Standalone and client, both generate the certificate authority, keystores, truststores.
Sorry, I don't see the difference.